# Why does an Android activity choose to call destroy() rather than just stay in the paused state?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

As I am new to Android app development, one thing I have noticed is that even in the simplest of apps I create, on losing focus, there is a preference for the app to call destroy() rather that stay in a paused state.

I was wondering what factors drive this decision. Perhaps its the device itself. Perhaps there are some programming factors or priority settings that come into play.

I am comfortable with handling the destroy state, but I guess I would like know if I have any control over its frequency of occurrence. When focus is regained how do you minimise the performance hit caused by repeatedly having go through onCreate() rather than the preferred onResume()?

Comment: can you please post, how you change activity?
if you use finish() any where, activity will be destryed. If you call activity for result, activity will be destroyed too

Comment: @Yarh The change is triggered by the back button and by rotating the screen. I put debug in the life-cycle methods to capture the behaviour. I dont call finish() explicitely. Not sure what you mean by 'call activity for result'.

Comment: when you rotate screen, activity is rebuild. It is done to allow developer to make adjustments for new resolution